# PHP DOMXPath - expression to select a tr that contains an input with certain attribute

Tags: php, dom, xpath, expression

I have the following structure:

```
<table>
...
    <tr><td><input name="email" /></td></tr>
...
</table>
```

Question: what is the expression to select that tr based on the "name" attribute of the "input" tag? More specifically, I want to know if there is a way to do this without having to select the input and then go up the hierarchy doing ->parentNode->parentNode... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to set an ID or class element for the input?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a simple XPath expression that selects the wanted `tr` element and doesn't contain any reverse axes. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//table/tr[td/input/@name = 'email']
```

**This means**:

Select all `tr` elements that are children of a `table` and that have a child `td` that has a child `input` with arrtibute `name` whose value is the string `'email'`.

**Do note**: No reverse axis is used in the expression.

Comment: thank you, the other answer was pretty good too, but I stay with yours because you answered first and your solution doesn't use reverse axis - besides I learned some new technical terms here which I can play with now :)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
//input[@name="mail"]/ancestor::tr[1]
```

Note:a XPATH->query  doesn't return a specific element, it returns a nodeList(also if it's clear that there is only one item inside). You'll need do select the item using

```
nodeList->item(0);//returns the first item of the nodeList.
```

Comment: Your answer is pretty good (+1), I already knew about the query returning a list of nodes, but I didn't know that you could use that ancestor::tr[1] part; in fact, it's a whole new syntax for me as I am new to xpath.