# DOMDocument Query

Tags: php, domdocument

Hi I am very new to this World of DOMDocument,Im still learning and looking for xpath query use in DOMDocument.The html sometimes changes so a preg_match is not a good idea. .I need to get the values from a html file.This is the part of html i want to get. I would be happy if you could help me..

```
 <?php  
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML('<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="results">
    <tr class="header" bgcolor="#0000FF">
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>Name/AKAs</td>
    <td>Age</td>
    <td>Location</td>
    <td>Possible Relatives</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1.</td>
        <td>
            <a class="LN" href=""><b>Iron, Man E</b></a>
        </td>
        <td align="center">54</td>
        <td>
            <a href="">Canada, AK</a><br />
            <a href="">California, AK</a><br />
        </td>
        <td>
        
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="">View Details</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
              
    <tr><td>2.</td>
    <td>
    <a class="LN" href=""><b>Bat, Man E</b></a></td>
    <td align="center">26</td>
    <td>
    <a href="">Gotham, IA</a>
    <br /></td>
    <td>
    <a href=""> View Details</a></td></tr>
    </table>');
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $xquery = '//a[@class="LN"]';           
    $links = $xpath->query($xquery);   
    
    foreach ($links as $el) {
    echo strip_tags($doc->saveHTML($el)).'<br/>'; 
}

?>
```

How do I get the following value? I can only get `Iron, Man E`, and  `Bat, Man E`

```
Iron, Man E | 54 | Canada, AK;California, AK
Bat, Man E | 26 | Gotham, IA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$xquery = '//a'; // you will get all anchor tags now
$links = $xpath->query($xquery);   

foreach ($links as $el) {
   echo strip_tags($doc->saveHTML($el)).'<br/>'; 
}
```

Try this to get in a `single line`,

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$xquery = '//tr[td[a]]';           
$links = $xpath->query($xquery);   
foreach ($links as $el) {
    echo strip_tags($doc->saveHTML($el)).'<br/>'; 
}
```

Comment: @Snippet test the above answer I've made changes in it.

Comment: i tried your code and its almost correct. but i need to save tha Name,Age,and Location in different rows.

Comment: @Snippet you can use two `xpath` like `one for containing class` and other for `not containing class` Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324179/php-xpath-contains-class-and-does-not-contain-class and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811949/php-domxpath-expression-to-select-a-tr-that-contains-an-input-with-certain-att

Comment: is there a way i can get the 3 values and store it on an array like 
`array( array('Iron, Man E','54','Canada, AK;California, AK'));`

Comment: @Snippet you can use `explode` function for this, Read http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php Use `explode` after `strip_tags`

Answer (score 2):

My Answer is not about DomDocument Query but can solve your problem easily.

There is a Library named [SIMPLEHTMLDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) ! You can do great things with it.

Example :

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Full Documentation (Power of this Lib) is [Here.](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)