# Search sibling of by another child's value in XML

Tags: php, xml

I have a question regarding the processing of an XML file using DomDocument in PHP.

```
<managedObject class="class1" version="version1" distName="distName1" id="id1">
    <p name="a">Data I have</p>
    <p name="b">Some data</p>
    <p name="c">Some data</p>
    <p name="d">Data I need</p>
    <p name="e">Some data</p>
</managedObject>

<managedObject class="class2" version="version2" distName="distName2" id="id2">
    <p name="a">Some data</p>
    <p name="b">Some data</p>
    <p name="c">Some data</p>
    <p name="d">Some data</p>
    <p name="e">Some data</p>
</managedObject>
```

By only knowing the "a" element, could I get the "d" element, but only if the parent have a certain class and version?

So far I've had a few tries, most recent being:

```
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, 'class1')][contains(@version, 'version1')]/*[contains(@name, 'a')]");
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
            $Array[$i] = $node;
        }
```

I used this to see at least some properties of the node but it doesn't return anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is your current method of selecting/finding "a" ?

Comment: `//managedObject[@class='class1'][@version='version1']/p[@name='a']`  found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655944/domdocument-query

Comment: can the match be based off the string `Data I have` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following `xpath` to locate `<p name="d">Data I need</p>`

```
//managedobject[@class='class1'][@version='version1']/p[@name='a']/following-sibling::p[@name='d']
```

`//managedobject[@class='class1'][@version='version1']/p[@name='a']` will specify your parent element with specific class and version and `a` element

And `/following-sibling::p[@name='d']` will locate your `d` element which is sibling of `a`

Answer (score 0):

If you can work from `Data I have` and work back, an Xpath of `//p[@name="d" and ../p[@name="a"]/text() = "Data I have" and parent::*[@version="version1"]]` should be able to get you what you need

otherwise a sibling and parent check can be done with `//p[@name="d" and ../p[@name="a"] and parent::*[@version="version1"]]`